# NHibernate - will entities retrieved by Linq be updatable?

Tags: nhibernate, repository-pattern

If I have an entity `Foo` which I'm persisting using NHibernate and I retrieve it using Linq like so:

```
var foos = FooRepository.GetFoos.Where(x => x.LikesWearningFunnyHats == true);
```

I then dirty each `Foo` like so:

```
foo.LikesWearingFunnyHats = false;
```

And tell the repository to save it:

```
FooRepository.Save(foo);
```

I'm currently finding that the `Foo`s are NOT being saved. Is this because I'm retrieving them using Linq rather than by ID or through an association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be because you're using Linq. The Linq expression tree is just translated into the same ANTLR primitives that an IQuery or HQL string would be, and from there to SQL.

Make sure you're flushing the Session, and/or committing the Transaction inherent in that Session, after completing a persistence operation. You should understand that NHibernate provides a layer of separation between you and the database, and is designed to decide when to send updates to the DB, to economize on round trips to the DB server. Usually, it does so in "batches"; it'll collect ten or twenty statements before pushing them as one batch to SQL Server. If you're doing smaller units of work than that at one time, you must override its decision to hold off on sending the update by forcing the session to perform a SQL update, using the ForceFlush() method.

It would be best to make this externally controllable, by exposing methods of the Session or its containing Repository to create, commit and rollback transactions within the Session.

Comment: Okay, so it's not that, it's something else. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I need to call Flush() on the ISession. I had assumed that calling Dispose() would also flush it, but no. I was confused because new instances added to the Foos collection were being saved, but dirtied existing instances were not. I still don't understand why this is.

Comment: New instances of objects need an ID when saved, so the session can uniquely identify them. If that ID is provided by an Identity column (common), only the DB can provide it, so NH "eagerly" inserts new records to get that ID back. However, an existing object already has an ID, so it can be kept in-session and used/changed by code indefinitely without necessarily needing to push the changes back to the DB (until you tell it the work is done and to save the changes).

Comment: Wow! What a clear and detailed explanation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think is not actually saved ? Try to call session.Flush() and ensure committing the transaction to see if NH will issue the proper command. Event strategy for fetching  the entity should not matter.

Comment: I know it's not being saved because no UPDATES are being sent to the database. I need to find out why now.

Comment: try please to call session.flush: no update is because NH does not do the update as you call it, but it does it at once.